# Centering Submenu

Tags: css, navigation, navbar, centering

I've read all the questions concerning centering submenus. But I don't get my problem solved.

I have a simple navigation bar with 2 submenus.
You can find it here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xqkde7u/).

```css
ul#nav, ul#sub1, ul#sub2 {
 list-style-type: none;
}
ul#nav {
 position: relative;
}
ul#nav li {
 width: 125px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 4px;
}
ul#nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 width: 125px;
 height: 25px;
 line-height: 25px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #000;
} 
ul#sub1 a, ul#sub2 a { 
 margin-top: 4px;
}
ul#nav li:hover > a { 
 background-color: #6E6E6E;
 color: #FFF;
}
ul#nav li:hover a:hover {  
 background-color: #E2E2E2;
 color: #000;
}
ul#sub1, ul#sub2 {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
}
ul#nav li:hover ul#sub1 {
 display: block;
}
ul#sub1 li:hover ul#sub2 {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul id="nav">
     <li><a href="#">Reisen</a>
         <ul id="sub1">
             <li><a href="#">Europa</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Amerika</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Asien</a>
                 <ul id="sub2">
                     <li><a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bhutan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vietnam</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Afrika</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Australien</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Magazin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Karriere</a>
            <ul id="sub1">
                <li><a href="#">Thema 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Thema 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Thema 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

I want the submenu centered. When I hover over "Reisen" the submenu gets the same width like the main menu.
When I hover over "Karriere", I want the submenu centered under "Karriere" and not positioned left under "Reisen".

I was thinking of a span-element to the button "Karriere" but I couldn't solve it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really now if this is what you're looking for or not, but maybe something like this?

Note: I made a few changes to your CSS and HTML, mainly changing everything to use classes instead of IDs

**[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4xqkde7u/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<nav>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Reisen</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">Europa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Amerika</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Asien</a>
                <ul class="sub-second">
                    <li><a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bhutan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vietnam</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Afrika</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Australien</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Magazin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Karriere</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">Thema 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thema 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thema 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul#nav, ul.sub {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul#nav {
    position: relative;
}
ul#nav li {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
}
ul#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #000;
}   
ul.sub a { 
    margin-top: 4px;
}
ul#nav li:hover > a { 
    background-color: #6E6E6E;
    color: #FFF;
}
ul#nav li:hover a:hover {  
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
    color: #000;
} 
ul.sub {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.sub-second { 
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    left:100px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.sub {
    display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.sub li:hover ul.sub-second {
    display:block;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realized that there are some issues with my boilerplate and normalize.css.